# how to change dropzone url dynamically with dropdown selected changed event

Tags: jquery, dropzone.js

Url is not changing in dropdown selected changed event. Iam passing dropdown selected value to url parameter.

I have three values in a dropdown.For each value in the dropdown I have different files to display.Initially I have  selected first dropdown, url is appending correctly.But when I select another dropdown from the list again the old url is still present and the first selected file is displaying.I need to get different url path for different values.

I have  tried above code but its not working.....

`Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;`

```
$(document).on('change','#ddlcategory',function() {
    var myDPZone = new Dropzone("#regular", {
        url: "someurl.html?type=" + $('#ddlcategory').val()
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it might not generate a new dropzone each time, since the first time you create a dropzone on #regular, but the dropzone never goes away after that. It might be easier to keep the one dropzone and just change its url when you load:

```
var myDPZone = new Dropzone("#regular");
$(document).on('change','#ddlcategory',function() {
    myDPZone.options.url = "someurl.html?type=" + $('#ddlcategory').val();
});
```

You can try playing around with myDPZone.disable() as well, but I don't know of a way to completely remove the dropzone and create a new one from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Global variable as url param, in dropzone you could not make changes of url after successful initiallization.

```
var _paramA=null;
var _paramB=null;
 $(document).on('change', '#paramDDLA', function () {

            _paramA= $(this).val();
           

        });
 $(document).on('change', '#paramDDLB', function () {

            _paramB= $(this).val();
           

        });
dropzone = function(){
     var currentFile = null;
                dropzone = $('#attachment').dropzone({
                    // dictDefaultMessage: 'Upload Attachment',
                    acceptedFiles: 'audio/*',
                    maxFiles: 1,
                    maxFilesize: 50,
                    maxThumbnailFilesize: 2,

                    url: "/Controller/Actionanme?paramA=" + _paramA + "&paramB=" + _paramB,
                    init: function () {

                        this.on("addedfile", function (file) {
                            if (currentFile) {
                                //this.removeFile(currentFile);
                                dictDefaultMessage: 'Upload';
                            }
                            currentFile = file;
                        });

                        this.on("queuecomplete", function (file) {
                            // console.log(file);
                        });
                        this.on("processing", function (file) {
                                url: "/Controller/Actionanme?paramA=" + _paramA + "&paramB=" + _paramB,;
                        });
                        this.on("error", function (file, message) {
                            //  alert(message);
                            toastr.error(message);
                            //this.removeFile(file);
                        });
                        this.on("success", function (file, resp) {
                            // console.log('file, resp ' ,file, resp);
                            if (resp) {
                               
                            }

                        });
                    }
                });
}
```